# Dealing with simple limit of a trigonometric function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

I'm dealing with simple function limit. I believe I haven't made any calculating mistakes this far, yet the solution is (wrong) dead end.

$$ \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{\sin^3x} = \Bigg[\frac{1-1}{0}\Bigg] = \Bigg[\frac{0}{0}\Bigg] = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{\frac{\tan x}{x}x-\frac{\sin x}{x}x}{\sin^3x} = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{x(\frac{\tan x}{x}- \frac{\sin x}{x})}{\sin^3x}$$

I have no idea how to proceed further. What to do with the denominator. Also the numerator in its current state converges to: $$ \big[ 0 (1-1) \big] = \big[0\big]$$
which is problematic since correct solution is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Help's appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sin x\ne0$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x\left(\dfrac{\tan x}x-\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)}{\sin^3x}$$ is of the form $$\dfrac00$$ which is [Indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) .

Try

As $x\to0\sin x\to0\implies \sin x\ne0$

$$\dfrac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin^3x}=\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\cos x\sin^2x}$$

Again, $$\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\sin^2x}=\dfrac{1-\cos x}{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}=\dfrac1{1+\cos x}$$ for $1-\cos x\ne0\iff\cos x\ne1$ which is true as $x\to0$

Comment: Um what about "$\sin^3$" in the denominator?

Comment: @weno, Use $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=1$  and 
$$\dfrac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin^3x}=\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\cos x\sin^2x}=\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\cos x(1-\cos^2x)}=?$$

Answer (score 2):

From Taylor expansion,

\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{\sin^3 x} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x+\frac13x^3-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!} \right)+o(x^3)}{x^3+o(x^3)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\left(\frac13+\frac16 \right)x^3}{x^3}\\
&= \frac13 + \frac16\\
&= \frac12\end{align}